# Align text left using jsPDF,jsPDF auto-table

Tags: angular, pdf, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

How to set header alignment left , I'm using jspdf and jspdf-auto table javascript library

[image]

**code**

```
const doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");
doc.autoTable({
  startY: 130,
  margin: { top: 80, bottom: 20 },
  didDrawPage: function (data) {
    data.settings.margin.top = 40;
  },
  bodyStyles: { 2: { halign: 'right' }, 4: { halign: 'right' }, 5: { halign: 'right' }, 6: { halign: 'right' }, 7: { halign: 'right' } },
  columnStyles: { 2: { halign: 'right' }, 4: { halign: 'right' }, 5: { halign: 'right' }, 6: { halign: 'right' }, 7: { halign: 'right' } },
  headStyles: { halign: 'right' }, // Purple
  body: this.PDFArray,
  columns: Object.keys(this.PDFArray[0]).map((column) => ({
    header: column,
    dataKey: column,
  })),
  theme: "plain",
  tableWidth: "auto",
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`headStyles: { halign: 'right' }` will style all the cells in the header row to be right aligned.

If you want to style individual header cells, replace the `headStyles` with `didParseCell`.

```js
    didParseCell: data => {
      if (data.cell && data.cell.section === 'head') {
        switch (data.cell.raw) {
          case "SI.":
          case "Particulars":
          case "Unit":
              data.cell.styles.halign = 'left'
            break;
          default:
            data.cell.styles.halign = 'right'
            break;
        }
      }
    }
```

You also follow the same approach to set other style properties like `font`,`fontSize`, `fontStyle`, `fillColor` among others.

Pay attention to the casing of your header column names otherwise the cells may not be formatted in the way you want.

Comment: Hi, just wanna say thanks.. it worked like magic!